# How can I remove a white space above my header using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

complete newbie here.
I am trying to edit a plugin page on my Wordpress website. There are three plugin pages, two look the same, but the other has a white space above the text.

This is the code on the page with the white space:

```
<div class="auditions-dashboard">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;line-height: 1;"><?php echo sprintf( __( 'Here You Can View & Shortlist Your Videos', 'auditions' ), $client_name ); ?></h3>
```

In comparison, this is the code on one of the pages that is styled nicely, without the white space:

```
<div class="auditions-dashboard">
    <h3 class="text-center"><?php echo sprintf( __( 'This is Your Shortlist Where You Can Download Your Videos', 'auditions' ), $client_name ); ?></h3>
```

I would be ever so grateful for any help on this!

Thank you.

Comment: The different is `line-height` attribute in your first example. If you remove it; it should remove the white space above the text.

Comment: Thank you so much @Samuel !
----
I tried taking the line height out, but it didn't help... please could you copy and paste the code without the line height but in case I misunderstood.. Thanks so much

Comment: Try using inspect element with your browser and try removing some css in real time in it and with that you can probably identify what's causing the spacing issue.

Comment: Thank you @JesusErwinSuarez ! I will give it a shot...

Answer (score 0):

Try using inspect element with your browser and try removing some css in real time in it and with that you can probably identify what's causing the spacing issue